# Ruby require 'file' and relative location

Tags: ruby, require, ruby-1.8, ruby-1.8.7, ruby-1.9.1

So I'm writing some rspec tests and I'm embarrassed at my lack of Ruby understanding.

I have a file structure that looks like the following:

- GUI_Tests/Tests/test_spec.rb
- GUI_Tests/windows_gui.rb
- GUI_Tests/upload_tool.rb

when I run spec for the test_spec.rb file, I require the upload_tool file to be included like so:

```
spec -r ../upload_tool -fs test_spec.rb
```

Then, the upload_tool requires windows_gui.rb, like so:

```
require '../windows_gui'
```

My question is, why so I have to reference windows_gui.rb relative to test_spec.rb (requiring the ../) rather than the upload_tool.rb?  This feels wrong to me, I'll want to use the upload_tool.rb out of context of the test specs, which means changing the requires each time.

Clearly I'm missing something, but if I don't reference relative to the test spec I get a file not found error.

Sorry for being so ignorant here, but I'm coming up empty handed.  Any thoughts appreciated.

BB

Comment: Don't feel bad - I find dealing with relative paths one of the most annoying things about ruby. I've listed it in [what are the things you would like improved in the ruby language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585457/what-are-the-things-you-would-like-improved-in-the-ruby-language/3261063#3261063)

Comment: August 2012 - Note that this post is now two years old.  Most folks are now on 1.9.2.  See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345412/relative-file-path-in-rspec also for the best solution (Feb 2012)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't. `require`s are relative to the current directory, which in your case was `GUI_Tests/Tests`. If you did this instead:

```
cd ..
spec -r upload_tool -fs Test/test_spec.rb
```

You would have to use this:

```
require 'windows_gui' # without '../'
```

The most common way to get around that problem is using `File.dirname(__FILE__)`:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'windows_gui')
```

NOTE: in Ruby 1.9.2 require changed it's defaults: [Ruby: require vs require_relative - best practice to workaround running in both Ruby <1.9.2 and >=1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333286/ruby-require-vs-require-relative-best-practice-to-workaround-running-in-both)

Comment: Perfect - like I said, I was embarrassed for even having to ask, but I'm glad I did.  That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Actually, `require` is *not* relative to the current directory, it is relative to the *search path* (i.e. the special constant `$LOAD_PATH` or its alias `$:` ). It just so happens that on older versions of Ruby (i.e. all except the not-yet-but-soon released 1.9.2), the current directory ( `.` ) is in the search path by default: `p $:.include?('.') # => true` . However, as of Ruby 1.9.2 that is no longer the case and shouldn't be relied upon. In Ruby 1.9, you could use `require_relative` which works relative to the source file it is called from instead of the search path.

Comment: @Jorg: But if I run this in 1.9: `$:.replace []; require '../somefile'`, it works.