# Relative File Path in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a RSpec test for a class in `/lib/classes` which needs access to a zip file (no upload). The file is stored in `/spec/fixtures/files/test.zip`. How do I input the correct path so it's environment agnostic, i.e. without absolute path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know (from looking every month or two) there is no better way that building something in `spec_helper` that uses the `__FILE__` value to grab the path to a know bit of content, then build your own helpers on top of that.

You can obviously use a path relative to `__FILE__` in the individual `*_spec.rb` file as well.

Comment: For others with the same issue: Since my spec resides in /spec/classes I ended up with: `File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../fixtures/files/test.zip'`

Comment: This works fine but it might be a little brittle in case you rearrange your specs. Of course one must not assume that you use Rails but if you have access to the projects root dir (Rails.root, Sinatra::Application.root) this might - or might not - be a more stable alternative.

Comment: to make this work across platforms, don't embed '/' in a string, instead use:
     File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'fixtures', 'files', 'test.zip')

Comment: Ruby also has require_relative -- introduced in 1.9.2, plus there's a gem that backports it to 1.8

Answer (score 16):

`Rails.root` will give you the app root, so

```
Rails.root.join "spec/fixtures/files/test.zip"
```

will give you the absolute path of your file, agnostic of the location of the app on your hard drive.

Comment: With rspec-rails you can access fixtures easier as described here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/file-fixture

Answer (score 10):

I've tackled this issue recently and here's what I came up with:

Define a constant in your `spec_helper.rb` (or equivalent) pointing to RSpec root:

```
RSPEC_ROOT = File.dirname __FILE__
```

Use this variable in your `*_spec.rb` (or equivalent) test files:

```
require 'spec_helper'

File.open("#{RSPEC_ROOT}/resources/example_data.json")
```

Why this solution?

- It doesn't make use of the location of the test file which may be
  subject to change (spec_helper is likely not)
- It doesn't require any additions to test files other than the already existing 
  `require 'spec_helper'`
- It doesn't depend on Rails (unlike `Rails.root`)

Here's a Gist: https://gist.github.com/thisismydesign/9dc142f89b82a07e413a45a5d2983b07