# Referencing file location in RSpec Rake task vs. rspec runner

Tags: ruby, rspec2

I have this directory structure:

```
project_dir
  spec
    person
      person_invalid_address_examples.yaml
      person_spec.rb
  rakefile.rb
```

The person_spec.rb has this piece of code in it:

```
describe "Create person tests"
  ...
  context "Person with invalid address" do
    invalid_address_examples = []
    File.open("person_invalid_address_examples.yaml", "r") do |file|
      invalid_address_examples = YAML::load(file)
    end
    invalid_address_examples.each do |example|
      it "Does not allow to create person with #{example[:description]}" do
        person.address = example[:value]
        result = person.create
        result.should_not be_success
      end
    end      
  end
  ...
end
```

Now when I run from the person directory `rspec person_spec.rb` everything works as expected. But if I run RSpec rake task from the rakefile I get `No such file or directory` error... The problem is obviously present also the other way round - if I configure filename with path relative to the rakefile location then RSpec rake task works fine but I get `No such file or directory` error from the rspec runner.. Is there a way to configure filename with path so that it is working for the RSpec rake task and Rspec runner at the same time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [relative File Path in RSpec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345412/relative-file-path-in-rspec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of

```
File.open("person_invalid_address_examples.yaml", "r")
```

It opens the file where the rspec is running. 
In your case you should define file more apparently something like this:

```
file_path = File.expand_path("person_invalid_address_examples.yaml", File.dirname(__FILE__))
File.open(file_path, "r")
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether your `File.open` works depends on the load path -- ruby looks up that relative path in the dirs in the current load path. You can look at the load path in the special `$:` variable.

Try looking at the value of this variable compared between both methods of executing the spec, and see how/if it differs.

It may be that the current working directory (basically, what directory you executed the command from, shows up in a list of paths as `.`) is on the load path, and the current working directory ends up different in your two different methods of running the spec.

Where is your yaml file located? Is your YAML file used only for testing, can you put it wherever you want?

You have various options, but they all depend on supplying either an absolute path, or a relative path that will always be on the load path.

1. Move the yml file to somewhere that is always on the load path. Your `spec` dir is probably already on the load path. You can put your yml in `./spec/example.yml`. Or put your yml in a subdir, but reference that subdir in the `open` too -- `spec/support/data/examples.yml`, and then `open "data/examples.yml"` (starting from a dir on the load path, `data/examples.yml` will resolve).
2. Or, ignoring the load path, you *could* use the special `__FILE__` variable to construct the complete path to your yml file, from it's relative location to the current file. `__FILE__` is the file path of the source file where the code referencing it is.
3. Or, probably better than 2, you could *add* a directory of example data to the load path in your `spec_helper.rb`, by constructing a path with `__FILE__`, and then adding it to the `$:` variable.  For instance, a `example_data` directory.

Probably #1 is sufficient for your needs though. Put the yml inside your `spec` directory -- or put it in a subdir of your `spec` directory, but include that subdir in the `open` argument.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put in your answer! If I could I would mark your answer as the final answer too. You provided explanation why the problem happened and several suggestions how to cope with it. On the other hand I really copy paste solution from the answer I marked as the final.. Anyway I find information in your answer very usefull so I upvoted it.